# PDF Generation from HTML generated by Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working with a client who has developed a solution with Adobe Business Catalyst. It has no server side code capabilities but does allow HTML access and alows you to access fields from javascript from the front end.

I have a list of images being output to a hidden field and am dynamically generating HTML to disdplay the images through javascript.

The requirement I have no is that I need to generate a PDF for the page, I have a Virtual Server that I can put a web service on and make a call to it via jQuery/ajax.

I just don't know how best to generate the PDF from the dynamically built page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$('#elem').html()` to get the HTML code.

Simply POST it to your server and use some HTML-to-PDF library to build the PDF file.

Comment: Just make sure that you use data urls for the images or use absolute URLs.

Comment: Anyone recommend any good opene soure HTML to PDF generators?